# How to improve the nonlinear fit to a data set

Tags: fitting, data

Some data to begin with

```
data = {{0, 0}, {0.05, 0.5786}, {0.5, 0.7202}, {1, 0.7902}, {2, 0.8978},
        {3, 0.9246}, {4, 0.9620}, {5, 0.993}, {6, 1}, {7, 1}, {8, 1}, 
        {9, 1}, {10, 1}};
```

I know from theory that the best fist to such data is the formula $0.5(1 + tanh(a + bx))$.

So I use the `NonlinearModelFit`

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, 0.5*(1 + Tanh[a*x + b]), {a, b, c}, x]
```

which gives

[image]

where the dots correspond to the data, while the solid line to the fit. As we can see the result is not so good.

So, is there a way to obtain a better fit to my data? When I say better I mean that the solid fit line should pass very close from all given data points.

Comment: "In theory there is no difference between theory and practice; in practice there is."  What are the consequences of your data not matching the theory?  Instrument problems?  Theory is wrong?  And if you just need a fit with no interpretation of the coefficients, why not just perform a linear interpolation between points?

Comment: are you sure about your data? The curve does not seem to match well a Tanh. If you remove the {0,0} point it gets much better. Is it possible that that point is wrong?

Comment: Actually just dropping the first point and fixing `c=1/2` is all you need. Note the given form can not pass through `(0,0)` and the data clearly asymptotes to 1 so you can fix `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestion give by george2079 works quite well.

```
workingData = Rest @ data;
fit = NonlinearModelFit[workingData, c (1 + Tanh[a x + b]), {a, b, c}, x]
Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.03},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point[workingData]}]
```

[image: plot]